# React Native: setState delay

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to set a state from a fetch response, but it seems it takes a while to update the state.

What I learned is that fetch is quick until it comes to setState. There, it takes about 3 seconds to update.

```
fetch(ENDPOINT)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({product : responseJson.product, related: responseJson.related, ready: true});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    }).done();
```

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: How did you  measure 3 sec delay ? You need to measure the difference between two "then" conditions.

Comment: The delay happens to setState and propagate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous.

From the docs of react itself if you see :-

`setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.`

You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Also, you can check something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: OK, I think i'm getting there. It seems my reactClasses are getting slow to render. Any tip?